# Domain of $\sqrt{\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}}$

Tags: functions, inequality, radicals, fractions, absolute-value

I need to find the domain of

$$\sqrt{\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}}$$
But there are a ton of different cases.
What is the smart way to do this?
Or rather, what are the steps I need to do in order to tackle this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I did the derivation step-by-step, and I also gave you a tip to do this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, first notice that the denominator cannot be $0$.So:

$$|x-1|-2\neq0$$
$$\implies x\neq-1,3\implies x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,3)\cup(3,+\infty)$$
For the square root notation, it requires that $$\dfrac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}\ge0$$
It requires that the denominator and the nominator must both be positive or negative$$|x-2|-3|2x+2|\ge0\implies x\in[-\dfrac{8}{5},-\dfrac{4}{7}]$$and$$|x-1|-2>0\implies x\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(3,+\infty)$$
So the first one is $$x\in[-\dfrac{8}{5},-1)$$
Then,
$$|x-2|-3|2x+2|\le0\implies x\in(-\infty,-\dfrac{8}{5}]\cup[-\dfrac{4}{7},+\infty)$$and$$|x-1|-2<0\implies x\in(-1,3)$$
So the second one is $$x\in[-\dfrac{4}{7},3)$$

So to find the domain, we need to get the union of these two sets, which is:
$$D=[-\dfrac{8}{5},-1)\cup[-\dfrac{4}{7},3)$$
Hint: Don't rush, analyze step by step you'll finally get the correct answer.

Comment: Your way also seems very nice.

Answer (score 2):

No free lunch here we need to distinguish the cases and solve  for the inequality

$$\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}\ge 0$$

with the condition $|x-1|-2\neq 0$ on the intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1,1]$, $(1,2]$ and$ (2,\infty)$.

---

**Edit**

Notably we have

- for $x\in (-\infty,-1)$

$$\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}\ge 0 \iff \frac{5x+8}{-x-1}\ge 0$$

$$\iff x\in\left[-\frac85,-1\right)$$

- for $x\in (-1,1]$

$$\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}\ge 0 \iff \frac{-7x-4}{-x-1}\ge 0$$

$$\iff x\in\left[-\frac47,1\right]$$

- for $x\in (1,2]$

$$\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}\ge 0 \iff \frac{-7x-4}{x-3}\ge 0$$

$$\iff x\in\left(1,2\right]$$

- for $x\in (2,\infty)$

$$\frac{|x-2|-3|2x+2|}{|x-1|-2}\ge 0 \iff \frac{-5x-8}{x-3}\ge 0$$

$$\iff x\in\left(2,3\right)$$

therefore

$$x\in\left[-\frac85,-1\right)\cup \left[-\frac47,3\right)$$

Comment: Not to be rude, may I ask you to be more specific on how to distinguish and solve? Would be very very helpful

Comment: I’m not stating to consider $x=3$ as a solution, it will be considered in the last interval. Note that I’ve stated solve the inequality with the condition $|x-1|-2\neq0$.

Comment: @Netanel Yes I can add some more detail if it can be useful.

Comment: Really Nice! @user

Comment: @KevinSong In my opinion use the distinction for intervals is always the best way to solve problems with absolute values. It can be quite long but it is the best way to avoid mistakes.

Comment: Yes, I  partly agree. Cuz I just made a mistake while I was writing the answer. @user

Comment: @user thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye